# How to know if my web site is blocked in China (Great Firewall of China)

Tags: security

I have a new site (with new domain), when I access it from China, it is being blocked. As the domain is a new domain, I am wondering if it is due to the site domain or in fact the IP we used is being banned before.

How to verify and fix?

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools which let you test your website behind the firewall, however in terms of why and the details I am affraid it is very unlikely that anyone here will be able to help. It is called the Great Firewall of China for a reason!